# Let FindMeetingTimes API search for avaialble rooms configured for the current Organization

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I created a dummy Office 365 Organizational setup and created few rooms as well. As it was my organization , I wanted to use `FindMeetingTimes` API to get the availability of attendees, *rooms* and the *organizer*.

I sent the following request body to the `GET` [url](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes).

```json
{
    "attendees": [{
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "Sid bhosle"
            },
            "type": "Required"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "cibcconf"
            },
            "type": "Required"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name": "Sid bhosle"
            },
            "type": "Required"
        }
    ],
    "timeConstraint": {
        "timeslots": [{
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2017-11-08T17:06:00",
                "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2017-11-09T17:35:59.0000000",
                "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
            }
        }],
        "activityDomain": "unrestricted"
    },
    "locationConstraint": {
        "isRequired": true,
        "suggestLocation": false,
        "locations": [{
                "displayName": "cibcconf",
                "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability": "true"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability": "true"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability": "true"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability": "true"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
    "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
    "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
}
```

The API returns a valid response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": [{
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "suggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-09T11:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-09T12:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [{
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [{
                    "displayName": "cibcconf",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "suggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T18:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T19:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [{
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [{
                    "displayName": "cibcconf",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "suggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T19:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [{
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [{
                    "displayName": "cibcconf",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "suggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T21:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [{
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [{
                    "displayName": "cibcconf",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "suggestionReason": "Suggested because it is one of the nearest times when all attendees are available.",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T21:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-11-08T22:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "UTC"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [{
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "sidbhosle@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "availability": "free",
                    "attendee": {
                        "type": "required",
                        "emailAddress": {
                            "address": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "locations": [{
                    "displayName": "cibcconf",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconf@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference101",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference101@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "cibcconference104",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "cibcconference104@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "D3secondflor",
                    "locationEmailAddress": "d3secondflor@CIBCmeeting.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know how to configure the request so that it works for other organizations as well. I want to get the list of all the rooms in some other organisation if logged in using the respective ID.

Let's take an example: I have to ensure that if Company A logs in using their credentials to My APP that it lists all the room configured in their company.

How do I achieve this?

I even tried to remove the `LocationConstraint` parameter but the locations were not displayed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding rooms isn't supported in production today but it is available from the `/beta` endpoint.

- [findRooms](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms) returns meeting rooms in the user's tenant or in a specific "room list".
- [findRoomLists](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findroomlists) returns all of the room lists defined within the user's tenant.

Comment: helps alot , from here I got integrate the output to the FindMeetingTimes API and then get the slots . But my question is , why this API was not available previously ?